# vbscript replace text - one works two breaks the whole thing

Tags: vbscript

I want this script to replace two values in the same text file instead of one.  However, if I uncomment line 12, it breaks the script.  Do I have to make this into a loop, or can I do multiple replaces?

```
Sub ReplaceTxt()
'Writes values we got earlier to our unattend file       '
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strSIFpath, ForReading)

   strText = objFile.ReadAll
   objFile.Close
   strNewText = Replace(strText, "***COMPNAME***", strCompname)
 '  strNewText = Replace(strText, "***Winkey***", strPoductkey)    '

   Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\$WIN_NT$.~BT\winnt.sif", ForWriting)
   objFile.WriteLine strNewText
   objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: you should have clarified that you want to print out each replacement, otherwise Frederik's code should work for you if you want to replace both at the same time and then print it out.

Answer (score 6):

I think you will want to do the second replace on the string returned by the first one:

```
strNewText = Replace(strText, "***COMPNAME***", strCompname)
strNewText = Replace(strNewText , "***Winkey***", strPoductkey)
```

Otherwise you will lose the first replace, and only the second one will appear in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub ReplaceTxt() 'Writes values we got earlier to our unattend file' 
  Const ForReading = 1
  Const ForWriting = 2

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strSIFpath, ForReading)

  strText = objFile.ReadAll
  objFile.Close

  strText = Replace(strText, "COMPNAME", strCompname)
  strText = Replace(strText, "Winkey", strPoductkey)

  Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\$WIN_NT$.~BT\winnt.sif", ForWriting)
  objFile.WriteLine strText
  objFile.Close
End Sub
```

By doing it the way you were, you were using the original, unused text twice, overwriting the first replace when you did the second.

Comment: objFile.WriteLine strNewText  should be   strText

Comment: Both of these do the same thing, first replace works, second is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure my if statement is ugly to the real coders out there, but here's how I got it to work

```
Sub ReplaceTxt() 'Writes values we got earlier to our unattend file' 
  Const ForReading = 1
  Const ForWriting = 2
  counter = 1

  For Each searchterm In Array("COMPNAME", "Winkey")
      Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strSIFpath, ForReading)

      strText = objFile.ReadAll
      objFile.Close

      If counter < 2 Then
         strText = Replace(strText, searchterm, strCompname)
      Else
         strText = Replace(strText, searchterm, strProductKey)
      End If

      Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\$WIN_NT$.~BT\winnt.sif", ForWriting)
      objFile.WriteLine strText
      objFile.Close
      counter = counter + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Thats easy.. Bueno ni tanto.. I was trying to do this some time. and i found the answer:

```
Sub ReplaceTxt()
 'Writes values we got earlier to our unattend file       '
 Const ForReading = 1
 Const ForWriting = 2

 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strSIFpath, ForReading)

 strText = objFile.ReadAll
 objFile.Close
 strNewText = Replace(strText, "***COMPNAME***", strCompname)
 strNewText2 = Replace(strNewText, "***Winkey***", strPoductkey)    '

 Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\$WIN_NT$.~BT\winnt.sif", ForWriting)
 objFile.WriteLine strNewText2
 objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Tanks, Gracias. José Villa From Culiacán, Sinaloa Mexico